# How to map a 1:1 relationship with Spring Data R2DBC?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

I have these simplified tables

```
CREATE TABLE address(
    id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    zip VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    city VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE customer(
    id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    address_fk VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (address_fk) REFERENCES address(id)
)
```

and these simplified Kotlin classes:

```
data class Address(val id: String, val zip: String, val city: String)
data class Kunde(val id: String?, val name: String, val address: Address)
```

When I use `@Column(address_fk)` for the property `address` I get a `ConverterNotFoundException` that no converter from `String` to `Address` was found. Also `@MappedCollection` instead of `@Column` doesn't look appropriate. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Relations are not supported yet in R2DBC 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/99

Comment: Thank you. At least now I know that I have to work around, e.g. by submitting 2 queries and do the join be eg `zip`ing the 2 `Mono`s.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.
I did "entity transfer object" where I am mapping Entity A to it, then in ETO object I have getters and setters where I can fetch required data from Entity B or Entity C. This solution is like reinventing the wheel but it works. Maybe this will help to solve your problem.

Comment: May be [lc-spring-data-r2dbc](https://github.com/lecousin/lc-spring-data-r2dbc) can help you ? It implements relationships (except many to many) so it seems easier than having to do it manually.

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina Why should it be a comment? It is the PERFECT answer for this question as R2DBC does not support.

Comment: Why does Spring R2DBC which literally stands for Reactive Relational Database Connectivity even exist if it doesn't support relationships ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an alternative solution.

Take a look into Micronaut and Hibernate reactive. It supports all sorts of things we got used to in spring/jpa, like pagination, relations and even JPA-QL custom queries.

All this is done using reactive streams and is non-blocking. (True magic)

More info https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#hibernateReactive